# Why is OuterXml not producing a string value after modifying XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the below Powershell code where, when executed, the `$b4` has a string value, but once I modify the DOM in any way and try to access XmlDocument properties, such as OuterXml, I get no value in `$after`.

I believe this is some type of casting issue but, I cannot determine the cause.

```
$xml = [xml]"<root></root>"
$comment = $xml.CreateComment("<!-- added from comment -->" )
$b4 = $xml.OuterXml #this has a value as expected
$xml.FirstChild.AppendChild($comment)
$after = $xml.OuterXml  #This is empty string or null
```

How can I get the OuterXml value of $xml after modifying the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you just need to remove `<!--` and `-->` when creating the comment. Like this:

```
$xml = [xml]"<root></root>"

$comment = $xml.CreateComment("added from comment") #From here
$b4 = $xml.OuterXml #this has a value as expected

$xml.FirstChild.AppendChild($comment)
$after = $xml.OuterXml  #Not null
```

Comment: Ugh, thanks. Is there an easy way to see that error?  ISE and Visual Studio gave me nothing and still showed the XmlDocument object.

Comment: That I know of? Nope. I'm currently working with `XML` a bit and it would be great to have a simple debug tool for this. I just do experiments and see if it works or fails.